# Collapse content when another is open html css javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to collapse a button when another is clicked. I tried all the possible ways to do this, but couldn't find the solution. Here is the HTML and JavaScript code.

//HTML Code

```
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

//JavaScript

```
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing all "active" class names and the add the class name to the one that was clicked.

I made a parent element so that you can just have one event listener (and testing if a button was clicked).

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

document.getElementById('tabs').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
    [...coll].forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'));
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.collapsible + .content {
  display: none;
}

.collapsible.active + .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabs">
  <button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (let j = 0; j < coll.length; j++) {
        coll[j].classList.remove("active");
    }
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible + .content {
  display: none;
}

.collapsible.active + .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```